# Image Magick Fatal Error unexplained

Tags: php, imagick

I am doing a simple thing of converting a pdf file into images. pdf has 3 pages.

```
 13        $imagick = new Imagick();
 14        $imagick->readImage('C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\ds.pdf');
 15        $imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg',false);
```

and the error on my site is:

> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\menu.php on line 14

Comment: It seems like some sort of issue in reading the file, but there's really not enough information for anyone to diagnose this effectively. At a very wild guess, I'd say it's to do with the fact that you seem to be developing on Windows ("C:\"), and I can't imagine Image Magick works nicely in Windows...

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, so and other recommendations for converting pdf to jpg on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Just use front slashes:

```
$imagick->readImage('C:/xampp/htdocs/mod/ds.pdf');
```

Comment: it is still same